# Windows 10 - Scripting setting: "Use Previous Version of Microsoft IME"?

Tags: windows, localization, keyboard, language

We're deploying a fleet of full screen browser based kiosks on Win10.  They need to have multilanguage functionality.  I've managed to script most of the setup, but there's an annoying problem:  The new version of the Chinese and Japanese IMEs only want to exist on the system tray, which gets hidden by our full screen browser.

There's a number of settings that can change the Language Bar to an always-on-top floating version, and to revert the Chinese and Japanese IMEs to an older version which can exist on the floating language bar.  But I'm struggling to figure out how to script these settings, it's not practical to set them manually for each device.

The settings are found in:

Settings > Language > Keyboard > **Use the Desktop language bar when it's available**

Settings > Language > Keyboard > Language Bar Options > Language Bar > **Floating on Desktop**

Settings > Language > Chinese (Simplified, China) > Options > Microsoft Pinyin > Options > General > **Compatibility:Use Previous Version of Microsoft Pinyin**

Settings > Language > Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan) > Options > Microsoft Bopomofo > Options > General > **Compatibility:Use Previous Version of Microsoft Bopomofo**

Settings > Language > Japanese > Options > Microsoft IME > Options > General > **Compatibility:Use Previous Version of Microsoft IME**

I previously had some success scripting another setting with this registry key:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IME\15.0\IMETC]
"Keyboard Layout Setting.New Phonetic"="0x00100024"

However I couldn't find an equivalent registry key for the settings that I mentioned above.  I tried using some registry trackers to see if anything changed when toggling the option, but I couldn't see any meaningful changes in all the noise.

I'm hoping for either some registry keys I can deploy, some powershell script I can run to directly toggle those settings, or maybe a way to manually configure those settings and back it up into a file I can copy to all the kiosks.  Or some other solution.

Edit:

I'm not able to set things up and then clone the device because sysprep kills all the language settings.

Thanks